# replace existing object on the stack with default constructed one

Tags: c++11, initialization

I would like to know the best/correct way to get back to the initial values of an object without playing with delete and new (everything must stay on the stack)

With this 2 classes:

```
static const int defaultValue{15};
class Foo
{
  private: 
     int val1{defaultValue};
     short val2{4};
} 
class LongStandingObject
{
   public:
     void resetFoo(int index);
   private:
     Foo foos[100];
}
```

If I need to reset some `foos` to their default values, what is the best way?

1. Create reset method in `Foo`

   ```
   void Foo::reset()
   {
      val1 = defaultValue;
      val2 = 4;
   }
   ```

   I don't really like the idea to have the values coming from 2 differents places and I do like to have the defaults values in the header next to the variable declaration.
2. Replace by a locally created Foo

   ```
   void LongStandingObject::resetFoo(int index)
   {
      foos[index] = Foo();
   }
   ```

   Am I heading to trouble when the local variable is destroyed?
3. Use memcpy

   ```
   void LongStandingObject::resetFoo(int index)
   {
      Foo foo;
      memcpy(foos[index], &foo, sizeof(Foo));
   }
   ```

   Maybe less readable...
4. Any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your #2 is just fine, and probably the most legible.

```
void LongStandingObject::resetFoo(int index)
{
   foos[index] = Foo();
}
```

There are no object lifetime issues here: the assignment operator is called on `foos[index]` to change its values to match the temporary object materialized from `Foo()`.  That is, the code is exactly equivalent to

```
{
    Foo tmp;
    foos[index].val1 = tmp.val1;
    foos[index].val2 = tmp.val2;
}
```

And if optimizations are enabled, almost any compiler will be able to just modify `foos[index]` directly without actually creating the temporary `Foo`.

If you do want a `Foo::reset()` function as well, you can use the same idea for it:

```
void Foo::reset()
{
    *this = Foo();
}
```

I would avoid using `memcpy`, since the program would become incorrect if you ever make changes to `Foo` that make it no longer trivially copyable.

Comment: Thanks aschelper, it was my prefered solution but I wanted to be sure that it was a correct one and indeed, once explained, it seems so logical ;) Thanks for the warning about memcpy as well

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use std::pair on each variable. Initialized with with `variable.first = variable.second = value`. After, every time you want to update the variable you set: `variable.second = new_value`. When you want to restore to the original, you set: `variable.second = variable.first`. You can improve it by writing a macro `RestoreDefault(var)` to make the code more readable.

For example:

```
#define RestoreDefault(var) ((var).second = (var).first)

// int val1{180}; // Instead of this line
std::pair<int,int> val1{ 180,180}; // <- this line

val1.second = 456;
RestoreDefault(val1);
```

If you want to **hardcoded** block any possibility to re-set later the default value, write:

```
std::pair<const int,int> val1{ 180,180}; // <- this line
```

-

Addition: Same principle for array:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    int x = 100;
    int y = 200;
};

#define RestoreArrDefault(var) ((var).second.fill((var).first))

// Use:

std::pair<Foo, std::array<Foo, 100>> FooAr, FooAr2;

// You can define different arrays with different defaults:
FooAr.first = { 180,360 }; // <- Customize FooAr defaults

// In that point FooAr default is 180,360 and FooAr2 default is 100,200

FooAr.second[3] = { 2,10 }; // <- Edit FooAr index-3 item
RestoreArrDefault(FooAr); // <- Restore Default
```

Comment: Hi Amit, thanks for your response but duplicating every single variable of each Foo object just to keep the default value available doesn't sound like a good idea. Especially in my case where it's for an embedded device with a limited amount of ram but even on a regular computer, it's really a waste of memory

Comment: I added an example how to implement the principle, in a savvy way, on array. Which one to choose depends on the granularity you seek to achieve, and on the type of the variable. The principle is to keep a pair: the default value as first & the modified value as second.